# Does a processor always reload CR3 when a VMEXIT occurs?

Tags: x86, intel, virtualization

Does a processor always reload CR3 when a VMEXIT occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about virtualization using Intel VMX technology, then yes. See section 27.5.1 of the Intel SDM.